# IgnoreExceptionTypes does not work (C# Webdriver)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have found that in `C#` whether using the `WebDriverWait class` or the `DefaultWait class`, in either case the `IgnoreExceptionTypes` method appears not to work.

I.e. in either case when running against my page a `StaleElementReferenceException` is thrown despite the fact I am instructing the code to ignore these exceptions.

`WebDriverWait` example :

```
public void WaitElementToBeClickable(IWebElement element)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
    }
```

DefaultWait example :

```
public IWebElement SafeWaitForDisplayed(IWebElement webElement) {

    var w = new DefaultWait<IWebElement>(webElement);
            w.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            w.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
            return w.Until(ctx =>
            {
                var elem = webElement;
                if (elem.Displayed)
                    return elem;
                else
                    return null;
            });
    }
```

Any suggestions gratefully received. There appears to be very little on the web about usage of this particular method and others have found it not to work also with no workarounds suggested.

Answer (score 6):

The `IgnoreExceptionTypes` will only last throughout the wait until it times out. I am using the `DefaultWait` and like you was expecting it to return null. It does not. When the timeout is reached it will throw the exception. Consequently I have enclosed it in a try catch to handle the exception appropriately on timeout.